# iOS Sprite Kit Platform Jumper Issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, game-engine

I am currently working on a platform jumper app but I am a total douche-noob.
Anyway, I found a tutorial online and started adjusting that code.

My problem is now: I created a SpriteKitNode that is a static image. I want to override it with a running (jumping/ attacking) animation. So I figured I could set he Atlastexture coordinates to the SpriteNode coordinates.
It even works (for now without animation). But when I start to move the MapchildNode (the static image), my own texture moves out of the screen, because the map starts to center the static Node. I tried to set my textures to the same coordinates as the Node for every Frame and even the console displays that the coordinates ARE the same. But nevertheless the texture moves away from the node.

Now as I said, I am a total noob. So please bear with me, if I am displaying the wrong lines of code now..

```
@implementation GameLevelScene

-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {
if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
[[SKTAudio sharedInstance] playBackgroundMusic:@"sim.mp3"];

self.backgroundColor = [SKColor colorWithRed:.4 green:.4 blue:.95 alpha:1.0];


self.map = [JSTileMap mapNamed:@"nun.tmx"];
[self addChild:self.map];
self.walls = [self.map layerNamed:@"walls"];
self.hazards = [self.map layerNamed:@"hazards"];

self.player = [[Player alloc] initWithImageNamed:@"koalio_stand"];
self.player.position = CGPointMake(100, 80);
self.player.zPosition = 15;
[self.map addChild:self.player];


// NOW THE ANIMATION
SKTextureAtlas *atlas = [SKTextureAtlas atlasNamed:@"noel"];
SKTexture *f1 = [atlas textureNamed:@"noel1.png"];
SKTexture *f2 = [atlas textureNamed:@"noel2.png"];
SKTexture *f3 = [atlas textureNamed:@"noel3.png"];
SKTexture *f4 = [atlas textureNamed:@"noel4.png"];
SKTexture *f5 = [atlas textureNamed:@"noel5.png"];
SKTexture *f6 = [atlas textureNamed:@"noel6.png"];
SKTexture *f7 = [atlas textureNamed:@"noel7.png"];
self.noel = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:f1];

[self addChild:self.noel];


NSArray *noelRunning = @[f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6, f7, f6, f5, f4, f3, f2, f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6, f7, f6, f5, f4, f3, f2, f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6, f7, f6, f5, f4, f3, f2, f1];
// LEARN TO LOOP!?

self.running = [SKAction animateWithTextures:noelRunning timePerFrame:0.03];

// END OF ANIMATION




self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
  }
  return self;
}
```

The static image being "koalio-stand.png"

So then there is the update method:

```
- (void)update:(NSTimeInterval)currentTime
{
  if (self.gameOver) return;

  NSTimeInterval delta = currentTime - self.previousUpdateTime;

if (delta > 0.02) {
delta = 0.02;
}

self.previousUpdateTime = currentTime;

[self.player update:delta];

//[self.noel runAction:self.running];


  [self checkForAndResolveCollisionsForPlayer:self.player forLayer:self.walls];
  [self handleHazardCollisions:self.player]; 
  [self checkForWin];


  [self setViewpointCenter:self.player.position];


}
```

And then there is the big troublemaker..? This method centers the view and it is exactly when the view is centered, that both the static image and my texture are moving apart (the static one staying in the middle, the texture moving out of the screen). But the console displays both as having the same coordinates.
I used >> self.player.position = self.noel.position <<

```
- (void)setViewpointCenter:(CGPoint)position {
  NSInteger x = MAX(position.x, self.size.width / 2);
  NSInteger y = MAX(position.y, self.size.height / 2);
  x = MIN(x, (self.map.mapSize.width * self.map.tileSize.width) - self.size.width / 2);
  y = MIN(y, (self.map.mapSize.height * self.map.tileSize.height) - self.size.height / 2);



  CGPoint actualPosition = CGPointMake(x, y);
  CGPoint centerOfView = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2, self.size.height/2);
  CGPoint viewPoint = CGPointSubtract(centerOfView, actualPosition);

  self.map.position = viewPoint;
  self.noel.position = self.player.position;
```

}

I am begging for your help =((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't clearly understand what are you trying to acomplish, but if your question is why `player` and `noel` objects are moving to different places when you assign them the same positions? the answer is that your variables `player` and `noel` are children of different parents, `player` is children of `self.map` and `noel` is children of `self`.

And the positions of the nodes are relative to his parents frames.

Comment: Thank you, Sir! That was very helpful! It does work how it is supposed to after I changed >> [self addChild:self.noel]; << into >> [self.map addChild:self.noel]; <<. So in case I would like to add enemies later, I should create them by >> [self.map addChild:self.enemyX]; << so they can interact?

Comment: What do you mean by interact?, the parent - child concept is a way of generating a relationship, and to aid you when moving groups of nodes (or applying actions), imagine that your have a a group of bees that are moving randomly in a defined space, and at the same time you are moving the whole group to another position. With the concept of parent and child, each bee can decide where to move inside his parent (the whole group) and at the same time you could move the parent.

Comment: Your game components could be inside your map node, or they could just be children of the SKScene, it's up to you deciding which aproach fits better your needs.
If it's your first try, don't expect to do it perfect, try, ask, look other people code and enjoy it.